# Forms in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create a simple search form in Symfony2.

This is my form:

```
<form action="/search" method="GET">
   <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search ...">
         <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn-u btn-u-lg" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
         </span>
   </div>
</form>
```

So my question is, what is the syntax of the form action? Do I just enter in the exact file that receives it? Or do I need to call some kind of config file?

Another question is how do I handle the search in the controller?

Thanks in advance!
Please note that I'm a total noob in Symfony2 :)

**EDIT**:

How do I handle the request if I would like a nice url like this: ".../search/value" instead of ".../search?q=value"?

Here is my action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/search/{value}", name="search")
 */
public function searchAction($value)
{

}
```

Comment: Use Symfony2's [`formBuilder`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html).

Answer (score 0):

in your action you need to put the logical path of your controller to do so call the twig function `{{path('you route alias')}}` , I assume that you have already set your route configuration.
to handle search in controller that's will depend on you re own logic but in the general case you will have to get the searched word using the request object taht should be some think like that:

```
public function searchAction(Request $request){
        $objet=$request->query->get("word");
       //do staff
        return $this->render('Your Bundle:views:searchResult.html.twig')
    }
```

Comment: now I did understand what you want,  in your controller  add value as argument of the action method yourAction($value){/* logic */}

Comment: I've updated my question with the action. Please show me how it is done:)

Comment: no you did'nt update your action method that should look like that : public function searchAction($value){ }

Comment: use javascript to change dynamicaly the path in your action="/search" you need to append the searched value to do so just add a onSubmit event listner that should be  somethink like that document.myform.action = "search/"+value;

Comment: Isn't there some other way to do it? It seems weird to do javascript on such a task

Comment: the only way to make some dynamic content in your client side is by javascript, in your case the action path of your form need to be set dynamicaly I think it's the only way

Answer (score 0):

In the form action, you need to enter the route that points to your controller. For example if you have a route that is set up to point to "/search" which uses your searchController's search method, you'd have to write action="/search" so when a user submits this form it is going to point to your controller's method.

In your controller you can either grab the $_GET variable with the name of the input (by the way you need to add a name for your input field to be accessible via the request superglobals), or pass the value directly in your url and put an optional variable after your "/search".

Comment: Pass an argument to your function let's say searchAction($searchTerm)...

$searchTerm will have the value passed to /search/{value}

Comment: There is no way to dynamically change the value of your action property. It's final value depends on what the user enters in the search field. You can do an ajax call on search/value , do the operations you need in the backend and then redirect to the page with the content you fetched from your database.